# Android marquee not show full text -show some characters and ... "3 Dot"

Tags: java, android

i try to add text to marquee but only show a part of it not full

example:  i like to show 123456789
and it shows  123..."3 Dot"

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/marqueText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="21dp" />
```

Comment: Ew marquee text.  I think 1996 is calling looking for their beloved <marquee> html tags...

Comment: i get text from xml in the web   but why it not show the full text but it show a part of it and ...